# Foil in microwave

Tags: microwave

My younger brother put foil in the microwave and sparks started coming up

and now every time my dad turns it on sparks come up what should we do?

Comment: Is the foil still in the microwave or do you still get sparks even though the foil has been removed?

Answer (score 2):

I think the foil shorted something out and the microwave should be repaired or thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

Decades ago I was a manager of a fast food shop.  One of the employees did exactly the same thing your brother did.  We stopped it, pulled the pizza and foil out and the microwave seemed fine, until I closed the door.  The glass shattered into hundreds of pieces. Get a new one.